# The .exe, created by Pyinstaller, closes when doing a multiplication matrix

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.8.3 in Anaconda. In my project, I am using Numpy (1.18.15), PyQT5, matplotlib (3.2.2) and scipy (1.5.0).

I created a .exe by Pyinstaller (3.6). It works properly if I open the .exe from the Anaconda Prompt. However, when I open it either double-clicking the file or from the cmd, it closes in certain circumstances. After testing it, I realized that, indeed, it closes when it does a matrix multiplication: A x B. These matrices are np.arrays of dimension 2. Indeed, they are:
A: [986 x 8]
B: [8 x 8]
Either the multiplication is done as "A@B" or "A.dot(B) the .exe closes if it has been opened by double-clicking the file or from the cmd. But it works properly if using Anaconda Prompt (or if using Spyder).

Comment: run the exe from a command prompt and you'll see the Python error message that's causing it to crash

Comment: there is something inside that method that cause error and exe to crash

Comment: @barny I have just tried it and there is no error message when using the command propmt and the application closes.

Comment: can you post [mre] that demonstrate  the problem?

Comment: @buran To test it, I have just defined the method as: def method(self, parameter) pass and the application does not close. So you are right (I thought it was related to the method call, and it does not). I will try to find the error and let you know.
Related to the "minimal reproducible example", I will do it and post it as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: if you just `pass` in your method, then of course nothing will happen. the actual code is what probably cause the problem.

Comment: @Buran I found the error. The error is due to a matrix multiplication: A x B. These matrices are np.arrays of dimension 2. Indeed, they are:
A: [986 x 8]
B: [8 x 8]
Either the multiplication is done as "A@B" or "A.dot(B) the .exe closes if it has been opened by double-clicking the file or from the cmd. But it works properly if using Anaconda Prompt (or if using Spyder).  It is curious because if I change the dimension matrix as:
A: [4 x 4]
B: [4 x 4]
it always works properly. So I guess the problem is related to the dimension matrix, isn't it?

Comment: It looks like this, but on other hand (i) it has to print something if there is error and you run it from cmd, not just close and (ii) it doesn't make sense why it would work fine when run py script and not - when exe if it's just the matrix dimensions.

Comment: @Buran I found it!! It is a problem with Anaconda. Numpy had to be reinstalled by pip. I dit it as: pip install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy. Now it works. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: It's great that you have your problem solved! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!! It is a problem with Anaconda. Numpy had to be reinstalled by pip. I did it as: pip install --user --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy. Now it works.